# Best way to apply changes conf file laradock

Tags: docker, xdebug, laradock

What is the best way to apply little changes in Laradock file without rebuilding?

I have to try to make my Laradock and Xdebug working in my Laravel project.
I have changed these files `laradock/workspace/xdebug.ini` and `laradock/php-fpm/xdebug.ini`.

It's just a little change configuration like change `xdebug.remote_host` or other, and then I rebuild with the following command:

```
docker-compose up -d --build php-fpm workspace
```

Rebuild takes time (too long) because it's downloading dependencies again and create a new image...

> <'none>

**Env information**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
- docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c

Answer (score 1):

You can use recreate to attache the new updates

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate php-fpm workspace
```